# Как в bash вывести строки по слову?

Tags: linux, bash

Имеется большой текстовый файл. Нужно найти в нём строку со словом **gzip** и вывести эту строку и строки после неё. Найти строку с **gzip** труда не составит. А как заставить bash вывести строки после данной? Нужно искать строго по слову, не порядку строки.

---

Вот вывод **binwalk**

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             Linux kernel ARM64 image, load offset: 0x80000, image size: 47910912 bytes, little endian, 4k page size,
123824        0x1E3B0         SHA256 hash constants, little endian
140400        0x22470         AES S-Box
140656        0x22570         AES Inverse S-Box
11258241      0xABC981        Certificate in DER format (x509 v3), header length: 4, sequence length: 21161
20471808      0x1386000       ELF, 64-bit LSB shared object, version 1 (SYSV)
20475904      0x1387000       ELF, 32-bit LSB shared object, ARM, version 1 (SYSV)
20498992      0x138CA30       gzip compressed data, maximum compression, from Unix, last modified: 1970-01-01 00:00:00 (null date)
20682636      0x13B978C       DES SP2, little endian
20683148      0x13B998C       DES SP1, little endian
20713280      0x13C0F40       CRC32 polynomial table, little endian
20825932      0x13DC74C       Intel x86 or x64 microcode, sig 0x0000000b, pf_mask 0x2012000, 2000-02-01, rev 0x-001, size 6
21348800      0x145C1C0       Neighborly text, "neighbor"
^C
```

Нужно оттуда найти decimal к gzip, затем decimal к следующему блоку. Думаю парсить вывод команды...

Comment: определённости ради, можешь дать пример входных данных и что нужно вывести?

Comment: ну если уж на то пошло - мне надо распарсить вывод **binwalk**. Начало нужной секции я смогу определить из вывода. А как достать её конец, который является, по сути, следующей строкой?

Comment: я не знаю, как выглядит вывод `binwalk`, так что, опять же, пример данных дай — «что есть» и «что хочешь получить»...

Comment: доп. информацию следует добавлять прямо в вопрос; под ним есть серенькая кнопочка [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Найти строку с gzip труда не составит. А как заставить bash вывести строки после данной?

Вывести найденную строку и следующую за ней проще всего с помощью `grep`:

```
grep -A1 gzip
```

Подробности в [`man grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)

> Нужно оттуда найти decimal к gzip, затем decimal к следующему блоку. Думаю парсить вывод команды...

Это можно сделать, например, с помощью `sed`'а как-то так:

```
sed -rne '/gzip/{s!(^[0-9]+).*!\1!p;n;s!(^[0-9]+).*!\1!p}'
```

Здесь:

- `/gzip/` — паттерн поиска
- `{...}` — блоr команд, которые выполняются, когда шаблон найден
- `s!(^[0-9]+).*!\1!p` — удаление из строки всего окромя первого числа и её печать
- `n` — прочитать следующую строку
- `s!(^[0-9]+).*!\1!p` — аналогично предыдущему